# Make or use delimiter to separate results

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

I have SQL output with multiple results:

```
 1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 0000000000
2963526113
test 7 8 000000001 9
 1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 0000000000
2963526113
test 7 8 000000001 9
```

The question is how to make delimiter or something else and to join every second and third row to the first and turn every SQL query to one row them in that output:

```
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 00000000002963526113 test 7 8 000000001 9
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 00000000002963526113 test 7 8 000000001 9
```

Comment: This is the same question as you asked an hour ago: [Move sql output data to one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911378/move-sql-output-data-to-one-row)

Comment: Yes but now is in different direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` with as many `-` as lines you want to join:

```
paste - - - < file
```

or

```
... | paste - - -
```

It returns:

```
I 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 0000000000  2963526113  test 7 8 000000001 9
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 0000000000   2963526113  test 7 8 000000001 9
```

If you need to use another delimiter instead of space, use `-d`: for example, `paste -d"|" - - - <file`.

Answer (score 2):

`Awk` love these !!

```
$ awk 'NR%3 == 0{print line;line=""; next} {line = line $0}' test
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 00000000002963526113
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 00000000002963526113
```

**What it does??**

- `NR%3 == 0` Checks if the number of records, `NR` is a multiple of `3` if yes prints the entire content of  `line` variable. Resets the `line` line variable and `next` causes it to read the next record
- `{line = line $0}` will be excecuted for `NR` is not a multiple of 3, copies the entire line `$0` onto `line` variable

**OR**

much simpler

```
$ awk '!(NR%3){print line;line=""; next} {line = line $0}' test
```

Comment: Could you tell me please in that case what is the meaning of "%" in NR%3, also seems not everything is included

Comment: @KalinBorisov I have added an explanation. Hope its clear now

Comment: Note `NR%3 == 0` is a bit too much explicit: `!(NR%3)` is enough.

Comment: @fedorqui i didn't think in that direction. Good point. Added in the answer. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu-awk and custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='\n[0-9]+ [A-Z]+ [0-9]+' '{gsub(/\n/, "")} NR==1{print; p=RT; next} 
        {gsub(/\n/, "", p); print p $0; p=RT}' file
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 00000000002963526113test 7 8 000000001 9
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242 4S 2 0080004 5 001 00014 6 000001 000000000000016973 6 0529540437 00000000002963526113test 7 8 000000001 9
```

PS: This will work for records that are **broken out it in any number of lines** as long as starting fields have this regex pattern: `[0-9]+ [A-Z]+ [0-9]+'`